# How to build association when I have 4 tables and 2 tables do not have any relationship with any table in sequelize library

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have 4 tables Class table has a relation with the section, A class can have multiple sections. and a section table that has no relationship with any table. Another table is a subject that has a relationship with the group table and the group table is independent.

So based on these tables how to build an association? I am trying to build this design: I am trying to add an extra which is group.

[image]

These are my models:

```
Class Model:
  Id
  name
  sectionId < relationship with section table
```

```
Section Model:
  Id
  sectionName
```

```
Group Model:
  Id
  GroupName (Ex: Science, Arts, Commerce)
```

```
Subject Model:
  Id
  SubjectName 
  Code
  Group < Relationship with Group table
```

I may need another table to achieve the design. But confused about How to do this. I need the data like the screenshot when I will findAll the data it will return something like the screenshot,
example:

```
[{name: 'name', Class: [{Class 4 (A)}, {Class 4 (B)}], Subject: [{English}, {Math}]}]
```

Is it possible in sequelize ?